# Partially activate a derivative

Tags: symbolic, formatting, variable-definitions

Is there a way to make an inactive derivative do some amount of simplification? For instance, say I have

```
Inactive[D][{{f,g},{u,v}},x]
```

I would like `D` to distribute into the matrix anyway without evaluating `D[f,x]` to `0`. Is this possible?

In the expressions I deal with it is often untenable to include all the arguments and still be able to view an appreciable fraction of the output. This is why I cannot simply write `f[x]` etc.

Comment: Take a look at `Thread`, e.g. `Thread/@Thread@Inactive[D][{{f,g},{u,v}},x]`

Comment: What about `Map[Inactive[D][#, x] &, {{f[x], g[x]}, {u[x], v[x]}}, {2}]`??

Comment: Thank you both but the advice is too specific to be helpful. Distribution over matrix entries is one of the simplifications that `D` can perform when active but hard-coding every such simplification every time it appears is not practical. Maybe there is no way to do what I desire-- have inactive symbols partially activate-- without simply doing the work manually.

Comment: Your comment makes it clear that it's unclear what you want. If `Inactive[D][{{f, g}, {u, v}}, x] /. Inactive[D][f_, v__] :> Function[Null, Inactive[D][#, v], Listable][f]` doesn't work, then maybe don't use `Inactive[D]` and use your own `myD`: `myD[f_List, v__] := Function[Null, myD[#, v], Listable][f];
myD[{{f, g}, {u, v}}, x]`. You could replace `myD -> Inactive[D]` later if needed. Or you can use `Format` or `MakeBoxes` to format `myD` like `Inactive[D]`.